# enum default values understanding

Tags: objective-c, enums

i am using objective-c to develop ios applications

i found in the documentations that enum have default values like this : "1<<0"

i don't understand this default value
example:

```
enum {
    UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber   = 1 << 0,
    UIDataDetectorTypeLink          = 1 << 1,
    UIDataDetectorTypeAddress       = 1 << 2,
    UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent = 1 << 3,
    UIDataDetectorTypeNone          = 0,
    UIDataDetectorTypeAll           = NSUIntegerMax
};
```

so, what is the default value for each element in this enum ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an enum with bitwise values or bit flags. Each value is an binary value in which only one bit is set to 1 and all the others are set to 0. That way you can store in a value as much flags as bits of an integer number has.

The shift left operator '<<' is a displacement of bits to the left or to the most significant side of the binary number. It is the same that calculating a "* 2" (times two) operation.

For example in the enum you have send in your question, the first value, UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber, is  1. The second one, UIDataDetectorTypeLink, is 2 and the third one, UIDataDetectorTypeAddress, is 4.

You combine that values as flags to set some different bits in the same integer:

```
NSInteger fooIntValue = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber | UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

As '|' operation is bitwise, the result will be a binary value ...0011, that is 3. And you are indicating that your variable fooIntValue has two flags set to true for two different properties.

Answer (score 2):

This << sign is for shifting bits to the left (multiplying by 2).

```
1 << 0 equals 1 (0b00000001)
1 << 1 equals 2 (0b00000010)
1 << 2 equals 4 (0b00000100)
```

Usually, if you dont asign any values, compiler will define first value as 0, second as 1 and so on. You can alway assign values yourself if you prefer (assignment that you're refering to is usually used for bitmasks, where each bit in a byte or a word has it's own meaning).