# Please explain uint32_t and 0x1 << 0 in Apple SpriteKit sample code

Tags: ios, operators, sprite-kit

I found a couple of lines in apples sample codes for SpriteKit

```
static const uint32_t missileCategory  =  0x1 << 0;
```

I know what `static const` is but what is an `uint32_t` and what does `0x1 << 0` mean? is it some sort of hex?

Comment: `uint32_t` is a name for an unsigned 32-bit integer type.  `0x1 << 0` is 1 shifted left zero times, which is kind of silly by itself but most likely there is a `0x1 << 1` on the next line down and more beyond that.  This assigns bit positions to the constants in that group.

Comment: (This is a very common pattern in C-based languages.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362084/difference-between-uint32-and-uint32-t

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<<` is [bitwise left shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) (multiply by 2) operator.

`<< 0` is the same as `*1`

So equivalent statement would be:

```
static const uint32_t missileCategory  =  0x1;
```

I wrote more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192693/653513).

For example:

`0x1 << 4` would return `0x10`.

Looking at it binary:

```
00000001 << 4 = 00010000
```

*Decimaly speaking* this would mean `1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2` or  `1 * 2^4`

And since this is `uint32_t` value it would actualy be

```
0x00000010
```

Comment: I think ive got the hang of it now, thanks for the explanation :)